# How to say "I had a fight with" and "to be angry with each other"

Tags: words, word-requests

I want to say "I had a fight with my girlfriend. Now we are angry with each other". I know how to say "to fight with someone" but it seems to have violent connotations. What is the verb to express oral arguments? Also is there a japanese equilvalent for "being angry with each other"?

Comment: We usually require prior research to be posted as part of the question. What did you find when you tried to look this up yourself (and why didn't a dictionary look-up answer your question)? Once you edit your question, it will automatically be considered for reopening.

Comment: @Earthliŋ The OP says they know how to say "to fight with someone".   It seems they've done enough research.  Putting a hold on the question just seems unfriendly.

Comment: @A.Ellett Oh, I didn't mean to come across as unfriendly. Usually, giving an own attempt helps potential answerers assess the level of Japanese. The OP also gets feedback as to how good their translation attempt was. Anyway, I'll reopen it for now.

Comment: @変幻出没 I (inadvertently) cleared your close vote by closing and reopening this question. Sorry!

Comment: It would definitely be helpful to know the OP's current state of knowledge, though.  For example, *how* does the OP know how to express 'to fight with someone' right now?  There are multiple ways to express that in Japanese.  An answer might say "Actually, that expression works for verbal altercations just as well", but they can't build on the OP's knowledge if we don't know what the OP's knowledge is.

Comment: In other words, we don't make people share their research effort because we want them to jump through hoops.  It's not to be unfriendly, either.  It's just because **if we know the OP's current state of knowledge, we can provide better, more specific answers**.  That's why it'd be helpful for the OP to edit their post and tell us what they know.

Comment: @snailboat I wasn't disagreeing with the request for more infomration.  But, the hold itself seems unfriendly.  Otherwise, the question is hung and no one can answer it if they feel they can provide an answer.  I would suspect that the OP is thinking of あらそう and doesn't know 喧{けん}嘩{か}.  But, I'm not answering because, though I know how to say, "I am angry" 怒る.  I'm not certain myself how to say "I'm angry at someone" let alone "We're angry at each other."

Comment: @A.Ellett Although it is not relevent here there is also 戦い for a fight and I think it goes pretty well with “it seems to have violent connotations” but that's just speculation.

Comment: @A.Ellett I'm assuming that the OP hasn't looked up something as simple as "argument", because, for example [on jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/argument) the first three common words where "argument" also means "quarrel" or "dispute" (and not "discussion") are precisely those listed in the answer below. Now we have a question that is answered by a simple dictionary look-up, _without_ any accompanying explanation.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I don't think it's a shortcoming of the question; it's a shortcoming in the answer.  The OP asked about "fight" not "argument" or "dispute".  Since these words have different connotations, a beginner in Japanese may not yet understand the need to consider alternate ways to express the same idea in English when searching a dictionary.  So, a better answer might include explaining this.  Note, for English to German or French, this consideration of alternatives is usually not necessary.  The OP may believe they've done their *due diligence* and not known what more they could have done.

Comment: @Earthliŋ We can always go in and edit and improve the answers provided, which I may do if Yuuichi doesn't.

Comment: In my experience, 喧嘩 is usually used when referring to a "lover's quarrel", which is normally resolved in time, and does not involve extreme anger or violence. That is what I get when I read this question, although it should have a more detailed description of the situation, since there are various terms in both languages.

Comment: To answer your questions about my research I checked multiple dictionaries (jisho.org and tangorin.com) but couldn't find an answer matching "to be angry with", only getting angry at, shouting at, and violent equivalents. I found いきどお.る but it didn't seem to fit. Also I knew how to say "I had a fight" simply from previous knowledge. Sorry for not providing this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oral arguments is translated as "口論" and "口喧嘩", so "I had a fight with my girlfriend." can be translated as "彼女と口論(or 口喧嘩)した。"

"We are angry with each other." is translated as "私たちは、お互いに怒っている" and "私たちは、お互いに腹を立てている".

Comment: Perhaps you can explain to the OP how they might have been able to find these answers in a dictionary look up.  As a non-native speaker of Japanese, it took me a long time to learn how to find adequate words to express my self in Japanese.  I would know the word I wanted to use in English, but my dictionaries only seemed to provide translations for different connotations of the word.  After a while, I learned to start thinking of different ways of expressing myself in English to figure out better how to express myself in Japanese.

Comment: These sorts of tricks are generally not necessary in English to German or French etc because these languages are so closely related.  If Japanese if the OP's first language, the OP may be very literal minded when looking up words.

Comment: The different between Japanese and English may be bigger than other languages but I think they are interesting for the reason.

Comment: @A.Ellett Thank you for your suggestion, as you are saying I had trouble finding this phrase in a dictionary, that is why I asked if there is a direct equivalent, as I was aware there might be some phrase with similar meaning, but which I couldn't find.